# Prove that for $a>2-2\log(2)$ the equation $e^x= 2x+a$ there are 2 distinct solution

Tags: real-analysis, roots, exponentiation, parametric

I have to prove that  $e^x= 2x+a$ for $a>2-2\log(2)$ there are 2 distinct solution. I've thought using Bolzano's theorem but I can't understand where to start, thanks in advance.

Edit: the solution to find are, at least, 2.

Edit: I've tried but I can't figure out how to deal with the parameter, $x = \log(2x + a)$ or alternate form like $x - \ln(e^x - a) - \ln 2 = 0$ but I can't continue.

Comment: What about that equation?

Comment: what do you mean? the equation is $e^x=2x+a$ and the problem says that the parameter is always more than $2-2log(2)$.

Comment: Have you tried calculus?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but I can't figure out how to deal with the parameter, $x= log(2x+a)$ or alternative form like $x-ln(e^x-a)-ln2 = 0$ but I can't continue.

Comment: @matteococciniglia Welcome to Math SE. Note I've put the text of your comment above into your question. In the future, please add your attempts initially to your question text since it shows you've made an effort, plus it gives other useful context such as what your particular issue(s) are, the sort of level of knowledge & techniques you have available to use, etc. This will help reduce the likelihood of your question being closed due to a lack of context, details or clarity, such as why this question was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$f(x) = e^x - 2x \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

First, to find any local minimum or maximum points, check the first derivative being $0$, i.e.,

$$f'(x) = e^x - 2 = 0 \implies x = \ln(2) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

The second derivative is $f''(x) = e^x \gt 0$, so $x = \ln(2)$ is a local minimum.

Note as $x \to -\infty$ that $e^x \to 0$ and $-2x \to \infty$, so $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = \infty$. Also, $e^x$ grows faster than any polynomial, including $2x$, so we have $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$.

Thus, the global minimum value for $f(x)$ occurs at $x = \ln(2)$, giving

$$f(\ln(2)) = e^{\ln(2)} - 2\ln(2) = 2 - 2\ln(2) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This shows that, for all $x$, we have

$$e^x - 2x \ge 2 - 2\ln(2) \iff e^x \ge 2x + (2 - 2\ln(2)) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, with

$$e^x = 2x + a \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

for $a = 2 - 2\ln(2)$, there's only $x = \ln(2)$ which satisfies \eqref{eq5A} while, since $f(x)$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}f(x) = \infty$, by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), for any $a \gt 2 - 2\ln(2)$, there's at least two values (with it actually being exactly $2$ since $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing for $x \lt \ln(2)$ and strictly increasing for $x \gt \ln(2)$) of $x$ which satisfies \eqref{eq5A}.